# display data from database in angularjs and json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, web-services

I am trying to display data from database in angularjs using webservice
But geting Error[object Object] while retriving data

My web method is:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Function GetData() As String
    Dim strCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=PC12\SQL2;Initial Catalog=TestData;User ID=abc;Password=xxxx; timeout=0;")
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from user", strCon)
    strCon.Open()
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dt)
    Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
    Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
        For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
        Next
        rows.Add(row)
    Next
    Return serializer.Serialize(rows)
End Function
```

My javascript to call webservice:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'WebService1.asmx/GetData',
            data: '{}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Result: " + data);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + errorThrown + XMLHttpRequest + textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please use code markup, very hard to read your code as is.

Comment: looks like response is an array, try response[0].d

Comment: tried response[0].d but still getting same error

Comment: can you log data to your console?

Comment: when i log data i got this error XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x800c0007, No data is available for the requested resource

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution

I haven't added  attribute in my web service.

Only Web services with a  attribute on the class definition can be called from script.

After adding got the data.